# Hibernate error with session factory

Tags: hibernate

I have got this `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>

      <session-factory>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping class="iger.User"/>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyAppBase</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>


        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> create </property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
      </session-factory>

< /hibernate-configuration>
```

this is where i try to create a session

```
SessionFactory factory= new Configuration().configure("iger/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = factory.openSession();

                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(regUser);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
```

and this i what i get

> Last cause: The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".

Why is that? What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post complete hibernate.cfg.xml source.

Comment: The spaces in the tags are just a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete `hibernate.cfg.xml`: it could be a problem in your mappings, take a look at this [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=954438)

Answer (score 0):

You have not link your entity class through which you could generate a table
, create like this
<mapping class=  > in your hibernate.cfg.xml